# Nested partial not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've got a partial in templates/layout/ called -header.hbs . In my application.hbs, I put {{partial 'layout/header'}} but when :I run the server it says Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find partial with name 'layout/header'. I am using ember-cli Any ideas?

My application.hbs:

```
{{partial 'layout/header'}}

<div class="container">

{{outlet}}

</div>
```

Comment: is the file called -header.hbs or _header.hbs? It should be the latter

Comment: It's called -header.hbs, when I used _header.hbs before it gave me a deprecation error and told me to use - instead of _. It doesn't work with "_" either.

Comment: are you using ember cli?

Comment: Yes, I am using ember-cli.

Comment: try it without the - or _ and make sure it is in app/templates/

Comment: In app/templates as -header.hbs and calling it with {{partial 'header'}} works. Just not app/templates/layout/-header.hbs and calling it with {{partial 'layout/header'}} doesn't.

Comment: For ember-cli its needs to be in templates/ not templates/layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ember-cli per its documentation partials should be within templates/foo.hbs directory to call a partial in your handlebars use the following code to render the template

```
{{partial "foo"}}
```

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I had this working in ember-rails and didn't realize that had changed in ember-cli. Thanks!

Comment: Weird! I got my {{partial 'layout/header'}} to work, I had to migrate my app to a whole new ember-cli folder.  I did something to screw it up, I noticed that it wasn't finding anything that was located in a folder, including some nested views. It's definitely working like this now though.